# Programa termina de forma inesperada sin mostrar error

Tags: c++

Esta trabando en unos módulos que me sirvieran en el desarrollo de otros programas para mis clases. Todo ha ido bien y al probarlos por separado han funcionado correctamente, pero ahora que los he utilizado en conjunto he notado algo raro, pues una clase que se encarga de obtener los factoriales de un número no funciona.

Tengo una función que se encarga de obtener el seno de un ángulo mediante una fórmula en la que se necesita el factorial del número, en este función pido los datos al usuario y luego instancio mi clase y es ahí donde el programa simplemente termina de ejecutarse y no muestra error alguno. Traté poniendo un `cout<<"ok";` después de la instancia de la clase y no lo muestra, por lo tanto el error ocurre al instanciar la clase.

Este es el código que tengo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

struct elemento
{
    long long int elemento;
    long long int factorial;
};

class Lista_factoriales {
    elemento *factoriales = new elemento[4];
    elemento ultimo;
    public:
        int size = 4;
        Lista_factoriales(){
            elemento F2, F3, F4, F5;
            F2.elemento = 2;
            F2.factorial = 2;

            F3.elemento = 3;
            F3.factorial = 6;

            F4.elemento= 4;
            F4.factorial = 24;

            F5.elemento = 5;
            F5.factorial = 120;
            this->factoriales[0]=F2;
            this->factoriales[1]=F3;
            this->factoriales[2]=F4;
            this->factoriales[3]=F5;
            this->ultimo = F5;
        }
        long long int factorial(int num){
            for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++){
                if(this->factoriales[i].elemento == num) return this->factoriales[i].factorial;
            }
            return this->getFactorial(num);
        }
        long long int getFactorial(int num){
            long long int ultimo = this->ultimo.elemento;
            long long int resultado = this->ultimo.factorial;
            if(ultimo==num) return this->ultimo.factorial;
            else if(ultimo<num){
                long long int i = ultimo+1;
                for(; i<=num; i++){
                    resultado*=i;
                }
            }
            elemento new_factorial;
            new_factorial.elemento = num;
            new_factorial.factorial = resultado;
            this->factoriales[this->size] = new_factorial;
            this->size++;
            this->ultimo = new_factorial;
            return resultado;
        }
};

struct Opcion
{
    const char* enunciado;
    void (*funcion)();
};

class Menu {
    Opcion *lista_opciones = new Opcion[0];
    const char* dialogo = "";
    public:
        int size_opt = 1;
        void add_option(const char* msg_opcion, void (*funcion)()){
            int i = size_opt-1;
            Opcion opcion;
            opcion.enunciado = msg_opcion;
            opcion.funcion = funcion;
            lista_opciones[i] = opcion;
            size_opt++;

        }
        void show(){
            for(int i=0; i<size_opt-1; i++){
                cout<<i+1<<") ";
                cout<<lista_opciones[i].enunciado<<endl;
            }
            int opt;
            while(1){
                cout<<">>> ";
                cin>>opt;
                if(opt>0 && opt<=size_opt-1) break;
                cout<<"La opción no es válida"<<endl;
            }
            lista_opciones[opt-1].funcion();
        }
};

void seno(){
    int terminos;
    int x;
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de terminos: ";
    cin>>terminos;
    cout<<"Ingrese el valor de x: ";
    cin>>x;

    Lista_factoriales facotriales;
    float resultado = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=terminos; i++){
        float num = pow(x, (2*i)+1);
        long long int fact = facotriales.factorial((2*i)+1);
        int signo = pow(-1, i);

        resultado += signo*(num/fact);
    }
    cout<<"El resultado es: "<< resultado;
}

void nesimo(){
    int num, n;
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero: ";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"Ingrese la posicion: ";
    cin>>n;
    int digito;
    digito = abs(num)/pow(10, n+1);
    cout<<"el dígito es: "<<digito%10;
}

int main(){
    Menu menu;
    menu.add_option("Sacar seno", seno);
    menu.add_option("n-esimo numero", nesimo);
    menu.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Pero lo más raro aún es que si llamo a la función `seno` directamente en el `main` si se ejecuta correctamente. Todo esto solo pasa con la función `seno` ya que la otra función si funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final había otro problema que era el mismo del anterior, un problema de gestión de la memoria. Pues, en la clase `Menu` inicializaba un arreglo de `Opcion` de tamaño `0` y a parte de eso, añadía más elementos de los que podía en el arreglo. Por alguna razón si me mostraba todo de forma correcta (en el menú).

El código del Menu quedaría así:

```cpp
struct Opcion
{
    Opcion() = default;
    Opcion( const char* enun, void(*func)() ) : enunciado{ enun }, funcion{ func } { };
    const char* enunciado;
    void (*funcion)();
};

class Menu {
    Opcion *lista_opciones = nullptr;
    const char* dialogo = "";
    int size_opt = 0;
    
    public:
    void add_option(const char* msg_opcion, void (*funcion)()){
        if (size_opt!=0){
            Opcion *temp_opcion = new Opcion[size_opt+1];
            for (int i = 0; i < size_opt; i++)
            {
                temp_opcion[i] = lista_opciones[i];
            }
            temp_opcion[size_opt] = Opcion(msg_opcion,  funcion);
            delete[] lista_opciones;
            lista_opciones = temp_opcion;
        }
        else{
            lista_opciones = new Opcion( Opcion(msg_opcion, funcion) );
        }
        ++size_opt;

    }
    
    void show(){
        for(int i=0; i<size_opt; i++){
            cout<<i+1<<") ";
            cout<<lista_opciones[i].enunciado<<endl;
        }
        int opt;
        while(1){
            if(dialogo) cout<<dialogo<<endl;
            cout<<">>> ";
            cin>>opt;
            if(opt>0 && opt<=size_opt) break;
            cout<<"La opción no es válida"<<endl;
        }
        lista_opciones[opt-1].funcion();
    }

};
```

Al llamar al método `add_option` se crea una nuevo array de un tamaño mayor al anterior, luego se copia los elementos del array anterior al nuevo arrray. Finalmente se crea la instancia de la nueva opción y se añade al nuevo array. Ya solo nos queda vaciar la memoria del anterior y asignarle el nuevo puntero.

Esto se puede simplificar si se usa `vector` como menciona @eferion en su respuesta. Y así fue como lo implementé para la clase `Lista_factorial`. Es buena opción, pero debido a que en mi clase recién se empieza a tocar el temas de punteros y arrays no sé si me dejan usarlo.

Answer (score 1):

```
this->factoriales[this->size] = new_factorial;
```

Dado que `this->factoriales` tiene capacidad para 4 elementos y que `this->size == 4`, en esta línea estás accediendo a memoria que no pertenece al array.

Por otro lado los arrays no pueden aumentar de tamaño, luego incrementar el valor de `size`, como haces justamente en la línea siguiente no te va a dar buenos resultados:

```
this->size++;
```

Si necesitas manejar un array que crezca en tamaño, es preferible usar `std::vector`. Este contenedor realiza toda la gestión de la memoria por ti. Tu solo te preocupas por añadir o quitar elementos y de darle algún uso a los valores que ahí añadas:

```
class Lista_factoriales
{
    std::vector<elemento> factoriales;

public:

    elemento const& Ultimo() const
    { return factoriales.back(); }

    size_t Size() const
    { return factoriales.size(); }

    Lista_factoriales()
        : factoriales {
            { 2, 2 }, { 3, 6 }, { 4, 24 }, { 5, 120 }
        }
    { }

    long long int getFactorial(int num)
    {
        // ...
        elemento new_factorial { num, resultado };
        factoriales.push_back(new_factorial);
        return resultado;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hice las modificaciones y sigo presentando el mismo problema :(

Comment: @Christian también has reemplazado todos los usos de `xxx = this->ultimo` por `xxx = this->Ultimo()` ??

Comment: Tampoco estaría de más los datos de un caso que te de error

Comment: Sí, cambie todo. En cuanto a los datos, sea lo que pongo en los datos para sacar el seno me da error.